# wp_enqueue_media() call causing fatal error

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a popup that's launched from the tinyMCE toolbar.

When I add `wp_enqueue_media()` call to the content of the popup, I get the following exception with the trace:

```
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1385
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-admin/media-upload.php:0
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP   2. require_once() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-admin/media-upload.php:16
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP   3. require_once() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-admin/admin.php:31
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP   4. require_once() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-load.php:37
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP   5. require_once() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-config.php:80
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP   6. include_once() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-settings.php:215
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP   7. ZipRecipes::zrdn_iframe_content($post_info = *uninitialized*, $get_info = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-content/plugins/zip-recipes/zip-recipes.php:48
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP   8. ZipRecipes::view($name = *uninitialized*, $args = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-content/plugins/zip-recipes/class.ziprecipes.php:1348
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP   9. include() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-content/plugins/zip-recipes/class.ziprecipes.php:1613
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP  10. wp_enqueue_media($args = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-content/plugins/zip-recipes/views/create-update-recipe.php:51
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP  11. get_allowed_mime_types($user = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-includes/media.php:2910
[28-May-2015 01:32:00 UTC] PHP  12. current_user_can($capability = *uninitialized*) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devblog/wp-includes/functions.php:2292
```

My main plugin file has this (relevant code):

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'media-upload.php') && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '&type=z_recipe') && !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '&wrt='))
{
    ZipRecipes::zrdn_iframe_content($_POST, $_REQUEST);
    exit;
}
```

and `zrdn_iframe_content` generates an plain .php file with only html and the following php in it:

```
<?php
// jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
// This will enqueue the Media Uploader script
wp_enqueue_media();
?>
```

What am I doing wrong to cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `wp_enqueue_media()` to be inside of a function that doesn't get run until WordPress has loaded the necessary files. This is [explained further in the WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_media) for the function.

For example:

```
function load_custom_code() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_code' );
```

Comment: Thanks! That resolves the exception. However, the content that's generated in `zrdn_iframe_content` is self-contained (meaning it's not something that's added to an admin page) and nothing shows up in the HTML. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try using [a different action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), so instead of `admin_enqueue_scripts` you could try `wp_enqueue_scripts` or `wp_loaded`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @bcole. I asked another question as this was getting a bit off topic for the question at hand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500327/launching-media-uploader-in-wordpress-from-another-popup