# Launching media uploader in WordPress from another popup

Tags: php, jquery, media, wordpress

I've added a button to tinyMCE's toolbar to launch a popup. The button calls `editor.windowManager.open(...)` and passes an argument of this sort as the URL:

`/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=SOME_POST_ID&type=z_recipe&tab=amd_zlrecipe&TB_iframe=true`

In my main plugin file, I have this code that generates some iframe code when the above URL is called:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'media-upload.php') && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '&type=z_recipe') && !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '&wrt='))
{
    ZipRecipes::zrdn_iframe_content($_POST, $_REQUEST);
    exit;
}
```

I found [a related answer about media uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668899/how-to-add-the-media-uploader-in-wordpress-plugin) which claimed that the following should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--suppress HtmlUnknownTarget -->
<head>
    <?php


    function load_custom_code() {
        // jQuery
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        // This will enqueue the Media Uploader script
        wp_enqueue_media();
    }
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_code' );
    ?>

</head>
<body id="amd-zlrecipe-uploader">
    <label for="image_url">Image</label>
    <input type="text" name="image_url" id="image_url" class="regular-text">
    <input type="button" name="upload-btn" id="upload-btn" class="button-secondary" value="Upload Image">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#upload-btn').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var image = wp.media({
                    title: 'Upload Image',
                    // mutiple: true if you want to upload multiple files at once
                    multiple: false
                }).open()
                    .on('select', function(e){
                        // This will return the selected image from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
                        var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
                        // We convert uploaded_image to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
                        // Output to the console uploaded_image
                        console.log(uploaded_image);
                        var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
                        // Let's assign the url value to the input field
                        $('#image_url').val(image_url);
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

However, the browser dev tools tell me that `jQuery` and `$` are not defined.

So, this could be solved either by fixing the way jQuery and the `wp_enqueue_media` is included or by changing the way my initial popup is created.

Any help you got, I can use.

Comment: you should use jQuery instead of $ and add this code in functions.php wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');

Comment: This is a plugin, so, not using `functions.php`.

Comment: I made changes you suggested but still getting `Can't find variable: jQuery`.

Comment: include that code in your plugin. and check whether you are include jquery library in your admin script or script

Comment: I'm still calling `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`, yes.

Comment: you are calling add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_code' );. so it will run on admin side only.

Comment: Did you try to put jQuery.noConflict(); before the  jQuery(document).ready(function($){